How to Deploy Only Remotion Player Without Remotion Studio for Rendering?
"I'm using Remotion, but when I try to deploy a Remotion template, Remotion Studio gets deployed instead of the template. Is it necessary to deploy Remotion Studio to an S3 bucket, or can I just deploy Remotion Player and still perform the rendering?"
"I followed the Remotion documentation to deploy my project, expecting the specific Remotion template to be deployed. However, instead of deploying just the template, Remotion Studio was also deployed. I tried to configure the deployment process to exclude Remotion Studio, but I couldn't find a way to do so."
